# Side menu in a second View doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, swrevealviewcontroller

[StoryBoard click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTFeC.png)
This is the print of my storyboard

I'm constructing a side menu with SWRevealViewController, but it doesn't work in my main view that is after the login scene, I connect the SWRevealViewController view with the login and the menu, I also tried to create a segue with the main view but nothing happens.

I implemented the code

```
        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuBtn.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuBtn.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
```

in the mainviewcontroller and the button doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, i had to do the segue of login to mainview in this way:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let sw = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController

self.view.window?.rootViewController = sw

let destinationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryboardID") as! NameOfViewController

let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationController)

sw.pushFrontViewController(navigationController, animated: true)
```